# Sorting array of object by specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have these object :

```
var obj1 = {
  endDateInMs : 125000001
};

var obj2 = {
  endDateInMs: 125000000
};

var obj3 = {
  endDateInMs: 125000002
};
```

and an array containing these objects :

```
var array1 = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
```

I would like to sort array1 by date of object. I would like to have the more recent first and the oldiest at the end of the array.

I do the following but it does'nt work :

```
function compare(a,b) {
                    if (a.endDateInMs < b.endDateInMs) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else if (a.endDateInMs > b.endDateInMs) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }

var arrayOfHistoryForThisItem = wall_card_array[item];

                    var newArraySorted = arrayOfHistoryForThisItem.sort(compare);
                    var lastElement = newArraySorted[0];
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Also, you are missing `return 0` in `compare(a,b)`.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Also, you are missing `return 0` in `compare(a,b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be just

```
array1.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.endDateInMs - a.endDateInMs;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g0aLs6tr/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the open source project http://www.jinqJs.com, its easy.

See http://jsfiddle.net/tford/epdy9z2e/

```
    //Use jsJinq.com open source library
var obj1 = {
  endDateInMs : 125000001
};

var obj2 = {
  endDateInMs: 125000000
};

var obj3 = {
  endDateInMs: 125000002
};

var array1Ascending = jinqJs().from(obj1, obj2, obj3).orderBy('endDateInMs').select();
var array1Descending = jinqJs().from(obj1, obj2, obj3).orderBy([{field:'endDateInMs', sort:'desc'}]).select();

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array1Ascending, null, 4) + '</pre>';

document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array1Descending, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```